# Using OR operator inside while

Tags: c, while-loop

I am new to stackoverflow and C programming and I have a really basic question.

Here is my code;

```
int main() {
    int level;


    printf("Select game level \n1 is easy, 2 is hard: ");
    scanf("%d", &level);

    while(level != 1 || level != 2) {
        printf("Please enter a accurate game level: ");
        scanf("%d", &level);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

While is runing everytime, even if I enter 1 or 2 for the level variable. But when I remove the OR operator it is working with 1 value. But I need to control both values. I tried this and it did not work too:

```
int main() {
    int level;


    printf("Select game level \n1 is easy, 2 is hard: ");
    scanf("%d", &level);

    if(level != 1 || level != 2) level = 0;

    while(level != 0) {
        printf("Please enter a accurate game level: ");
        scanf("%d", &level);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

And also, if I enter a string to scanf, while starts running without waiting for me to enter value to scanf.

Comment: Say `level != 1 || level != 2` repeatedly to yourself. Then, ask yourself if `level == 1` were true, which of those two conditions would still be true, thus satisfying the overall expression as true because of the `||` operator? How would that be different if the expression were `level != 1 && level != 2` instead?

Comment: `1 != 2` and vice versa

Comment: i was really thinking differently, i see it know. thank you very much. what about the string thing? how can I prevent the while going an infinite loop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Applying [De Morgan's Laws](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws) to this expression

```
(level != 1 || level != 2)
```

it is the same as

```
!((level == 1) && (level == 2))
```

Can the inner expression ever be true? Can `level` be *equal* `1` *and* be *equal* `2` at the same time? No, it cannot, never.